# Android KSOAP2 throws SocketTimeoutException

Tags: android, ksoap2

I have used the above library for SOAP objects in my Android project, in order to connect to a .NET web service. The application was working fine till I made some changes and also increased/decreased target API. It started throwing SocketTimeoutException and wont go away.

I am using **Android Developer Tools Build: v21.0.0-519525**

Any help is appreciated.

```
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "https://monitor.co.uk/";
    private static final String URL = "https://monitor.co.uk/WebService.asmx";

    private static final String GET_ID_METHOD = "GetId";
    private static final String GET_ID_SOAP_ACTION = "https://monitor.co.uk/GetId";
    public static String callGetIdWebService(String pass, String id, Context context)
    {
      String sRes = "";
      try 
      { 

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, GET_ID_METHOD);

            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("pass");
            pi.setValue(pass.toString());//"pass");// 
            pi.setType(pass.getClass());
            request.addProperty(pi);

            PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi2.setName("id");
            pi2.setValue(id.toString());
            pi2.setType(id.getClass());
            request.addProperty(pi2);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;

            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            httpTransport.debug = true;

            httpTransport.call(GET_ID_SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Object response = envelope.getResponse();

            httpTransport.debug = true;
            if(response.toString().equals("-1"))
            {
                sRes = "No records";
            }
            else
            {
                sRes = response.toString();
            }
      } 

      catch (Exception e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("EXCEPTION...", e.toString());

      }
      return sRes;
    }
```

Log Cat below:

```
01-28 17:39:34.213: W/System.err(16378): java.net.SocketTimeoutException
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:130)
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at com.example.notificationmanager.CreateNotificationActivity.callGetIdWebService(CreateNotificationActivity.java:94)
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at com.example.notificationmanager.CreateNotificationActivity.createNotification(CreateNotificationActivity.java:37)
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3095)
01-28 17:39:34.218: W/System.err(16378):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
01-28 17:39:34.223: W/System.err(16378):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14329)
01-28 17:39:34.223: W/System.err(16378):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
01-28 17:39:34.223: W/System.err(16378):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-28 17:39:34.223: W/System.err(16378):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-28 17:39:34.223: W/System.err(16378):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
01-28 17:39:34.223: W/System.err(16378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-28 17:39:34.228: W/System.err(16378):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-28 17:39:34.228: W/System.err(16378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
01-28 17:39:34.228: W/System.err(16378):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
01-28 17:39:34.228: W/System.err(16378):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Liaqat

Comment: post code your code and logcat.

Comment: Hi Mihail, I have updated the question. Please see the code and Log Cat I have posted above. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this fixed after I had another couple of Exceptions going on with the app and some other kind folk on my other question replied and suggested to use AsyncTask. Once got the AsyncTask working, this error also went away. So, guess this is fine to assume the issue was caused by the same problem with doing network operation on GUI activity.

Many thanks for your assistance.
Liaqat.

Answer (score 2):

interesting, while increasing/decreasing target APIs and playing around with manifest, please make sure you have the internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: The internet permission is there mihail. Anything else that comes to mind? I am just so annoyed by this error. Thanks.

Comment: well, I see that the connection is through https... Does it work if you try to access the method through http?

Comment: Mihail, just tested this with 'http' before this reply, the issue remains the same. Thanks

Comment: are you sure the service is accessible at all. Can you add it as a web reference in visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I have been using it till yesterday when I made the changes albeit not directly to SOAP object coding and the call. But to be 100% sure, I just tested it by adding it in Visual Studio as Service Reference.